# Magento 2 How to Disable Shipping Method Without Career Code

Tags: shipping

I want to completely disable shipping method without
career code use

Comment: is it not possibel with admin panel?

Comment: Admin > Store>Configuration>Sales>Shipping Methods
Select Shipping Method and set the Enabled field to No and then press the button Save Config.